# How do I create an SVN external from within an existing repo?

Tags: svn

I have a repo with a structure similar to this:

```
+- www
    +- stylesheets
    +- javascripts
    +- images
        +- thumbnails
```

Most of the repo only gets updated during a release.  But because of a CMS, the thumbnails are created in such a way that they never get added to the repo.  In fact, we want to track them in a separate repo.

Is it possible to create that `thumbnails` directory as an external repo within the existing repo that contains everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - an external just points to a different SVN-accessible location, which may or may not exist within the same repo.

I'll assume that your SVN setup is accessible over https; you'll need to adjust for your structure and access method.

So, if you want the thumbnails in the same repo but just in a different location, you can put them under a different directory in the existing repo:

```
- www
   - ...
   - images (with svn:externals property setting "thumbnails" to a remote
             location of https://example.com/svn/repo/thumbnails)
- thumbnails (real location)
```

Or in a different repo, if that makes more sense to your workflow:

```
(existing repo)
- www
   - ...
   - images (with svn:externals property setting "thumbnails" to a remote
             location of https://example.com/svn/thumbnailsrepo/thumbnails)

(new repo)
- thumbnails
```